# Split string and use in Like Command

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a string like `'from+google+world'`

I need to search the text for the entire three keywords at any place 
for single query we are using,

```
select * from tabl name 
where desc like '%from%' 
and desc like '%google%' 
and desc like '%world%'
```

How do I split the string and use it with the above query.
`@p1+@p2+@p3`

```
select * from tabl name 
where desc like '%@p1%' 
and desc like '%@p2%' 
and desc like '%@p3%'
```

Radu Gheorghiu : This command is 50 % helpful it was just splitting the String with De-Limiter i have to get the column which is having 3 splitted words for eg we have to get Desc like 'all @p3 things are @p1 going @p2 fine' and desc not like 'all @p3 things are @p1 going fine'

Answer (score 2):

This is the code you need and [here is a SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/14834)

```
with test as 
    (select 'from+google+world' str from dual  
    )  
    select regexp_substr (str, '[^+]+', 1, rownum) split  
    from test  
    connect by level <= length (regexp_replace (str, '[^+]+'))  + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this output??

```
from
google
world

WITH t AS (SELECT 'from+google+world' word FROM dual)
SELECT regexp_substr(word, '[[:alpha:]]+', 1, LEVEL) FROM T
CONNECT BY regexp_substr(word, '[[:alpha:]]+', 1, level) is not null;
```

Do you mean this output??

```
from
google
world

WITH t AS (SELECT 'from+google+world' word FROM dual)
SELECT regexp_substr(word, '[[:alpha:]]+', 1, LEVEL) FROM T
CONNECT BY regexp_substr(word, '[[:alpha:]]+', 1, level) is not null;
```

or if you're searching inside the table that contains any of these word, 
you can you `CONTAINS` function from oracle that is indexed:

Link here :http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28303/query.htm

And `CTXCAT` search here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/ctxcat-primer-090555.html

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE desc IN (
    SELECT regexp_substr('from+google+world','[^+]+', 1, level) FROM dual
    CONNECT BY regexp_substr('from+google+world', '[^+]+', 1, level)
    is not null
);
```